# How can I disable datadog agent from starting on system boot without disable/uninstall on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

We are using datadog agent for monitoring of our customer's systems. By default the datadog agent starts up on system boot but we need to disable to be started only when start command for datadog-agent is run. We are using datadog infrastructure monitoring for Ubuntu systems.

Tried searching through datadog documentation and as well on Google but to no avail.

Nearest thing found was [this Git issue](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/issues/437) but that too does not have solution on how to do it.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu... we gotta know if we're dealing with rc.d, systemd, init, etc...

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: I believe my answer is proper for that version of Ubuntu, if it doesn't work, let me know in the comments on the answer and I will update and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `sudo` privileges. Then:

`sudo systemctl stop datadog-agent`

followed by

`sudo systemctl disable datadog-agent`

then you will need to run the `datadog-agent` manually moving forward.